# Aligning both equal sign and implies, without RHS moving to extreme right

Tags: align, alignment

This is my piece:

```
\begin{flalign*}
g(bL)  &=& F(b,g(L))\\
\implies  g((1+\varepsilon)L) &=& F((1+\epsilon),g(L))\\
\implies   g((1+ \varepsilon)L)-g(L) &=& F((1+\epsilon),g(L))-F(1,g(L))
\end{flalign*}
```

[image: This is what it looks like:]

Comment: in ams alignments it is always `&=` not `&=&`

Comment: You are confusing the notation used for `eqnarray` with that of `align` and friends. The former uses `&=&` but the latter uses `&=`.

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity, why do you use `\varepsilon` in some cases and `\epsilon` in others?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want one of these alignments?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
 & & g(bL) &= F(b,g(L))\\
 & \implies & g((1+\varepsilon)L) &= F((1+\epsilon),g(L))\\
 & \implies & g((1+ \varepsilon)L)-g(L) &= F((1+\epsilon),g(L))-F(1,g(L))
\end{alignat*}
\vskip 1cm

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 & & g(bL) &= F(b,g(L))\\
 & \implies & g((1+\varepsilon)L) &= F((1+\epsilon),g(L))\\
 & \implies & g((1+ \varepsilon)L)-g(L) &= F((1+\epsilon),g(L))-F(1,g(L))
\end{alignat*}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]